# Amazon AWS multiple NICs to separate Web, and Cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, network-programming, amazon-vpc, ncache

We have a VPC setup on Amazon S3 where we have various application delivery web servers that communicate with a cluster of NCache in-memory caching servers, and a database server.

Trying to determine the bottleneck and how to properly scale; would it be possible and a good idea to create multiple NICs per instance and segment them so that a (or load balanced cluster) of NIC(s) on the web servers are load balanced, and then another dedicated NIC for traffic to the cache servers network, and another for the database.

Right now from monitoring on AWS, our cache servers are seeing around 600Mbps in and 1.5Gbps out, with very minimal load.

Comment: Do your logs suggest that this traffic is all legitimate?  Depending on what you mean by "minimal load," that seems like a very large amount of traffic.  It's not clear, though, why you think multiple "NICs" would help.  Are you talking about "ENIs" (elastic network interfaces)?  If so, those are virtual, not physical, so it isn't clear what that would accomplish... it would almost certainly not increase your available bandwidth.  Can you be more specific what problem you're having?

Comment: Multiple Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs) do not increase network bandwidth. The network bandwidth is related to the size of Amazon EC2 instance (Low, Moderate, High).

Comment: There is one NIC that is being used to access the database, cache, and outside world.  Data coming in from the outside world is minimal.  Data being sent to the cache cluster is basically 99% of the numbers above.  I was thinking segmenting the network and adding a dedicated team of cards for cache communication would likely resolve some of the bottleneck.

Comment: Use multiple NICs only if you are sure that there is a possibility of a network choke. If you do split your NIC, yes you will see a performance boost but how much that would be is another debate. You can also [split Cluster and Client IPs](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/help/ip-binding.html?mw=MjQw&q=bmlj&st=Mw==&sct=MA==&ms=AAAAAAAAAAAA)